# MySQL chained REPLACE?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE media 
WHERE id = 63212 AND description LIKE '%https://images.weserv.nl/%' 
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=http', 'http') 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '[img]https://blu.xyz/favicon.ico', '[img=35]https://blu.xyz/favicon.ico') 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '[img]http', '[img=400]http') 
SET description 
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=', 'https://') SET description = REPLACE(description, '&w=35', '') 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '&w=400', '') 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '&h=400', '') 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '&w=300', '') 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '&h=300', '');
```

I am getting the following in return:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 63212 AND description LIKE '%https://images.weserv.nl/%' SET descript' at line 1

Could anyone give me some guidance?

Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE media SET var1 = ..., column2 = ..., ... WHERE id = ... AND description LIKE ...`

Comment: So your saying WHERE id = 63212 AND description LIKE '%https://images.weserv.nl/%' should be moved after the set/replaces?

Comment: You can only have one `SET` clause in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @Barmar thats rough....so ill have to break this down to multiple queries. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @HDVinnie "One SET per query" does not mean "one assigning per query".

Comment: @Akina I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

`WHERE` statement should be after `SET` and only `1x SET` is allowed.

So like:

```
UPDATE media 
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=http', 'http') 
description = REPLACE(description, '[img]https://blu.xyz/favicon.ico', '[img=35]https://blu.xyz/favicon.ico'), 
description = REPLACE(description, '[img]http', '[img=400]http'), 
description = REPLACE(description, 'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=', 'https://'),
description = REPLACE(description, '&w=35', ''),
description = REPLACE(description, '&w=400', ''), 
description = REPLACE(description, '&h=400', ''), 
description = REPLACE(description, '&w=300', ''), 
description = REPLACE(description, '&h=300', '')
WHERE id = 63212 AND description LIKE '%https://images.weserv.nl/%' ;
```

Comment: Please mark it as correct if it saves your life :)

Comment: Missing commas at the end of each line in the SET clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems.

First, as others noted, the `WHERE` clause goes after the `SET` clause.

Second, you can't use multiple `SET` clauses. If you want to perform multiple replacements on a column, you have to nest them. I'll show how to do it for 3 replacements, you can extend it to all your replacements.

```
UPDATE media
SET description = 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(description, 'https://images.weserv.nl/?url=http', 'http'), 
            '[img]https://blu.xyz/favicon.ico', '[img=35]https://blu.xyz/favicon.ico'),
        '[img]http', '[img=400]http')
WHERE id = 63212 AND description LIKE '%https://images.weserv.nl/%'
```

Note that when you have nested replacements like this, they're process from the innermost outward. So if there are overlapping search strings, nest the most specific ones more deeply.